# Ruby on Rails - Import Data from a CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

I would like to import data from a CSV file into an existing database table.  I do not want to save the CSV file, just take the data from it and put it into the existing table.  I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

This is my table:

```
create_table "mouldings", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "suppliers_code"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "supplier_id"
  t.decimal  "length",         :precision => 3, :scale => 2
  t.decimal  "cost",           :precision => 4, :scale => 2
  t.integer  "width"
  t.integer  "depth"
end
```

Can you give me some code to show me the best way to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

```
require 'csv'    

csv_text = File.read('...')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  Moulding.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

Comment: You can put it in a Rake task, or in a controller action, or anywhere you like....

Comment: It worked perfectly. However I have a beginner-level question - when I tried to  browse described methods in Ruby and Rails API documentation I was unable to find them on place (I looked on official Ruby and Rails sites, API docs). 

E.g. I couldn't find what object returns CSV.parse(), I didn't find to_hash() and  with_indifferent_access() methods... 

Maybe I looked in wrong place or missed some basic principle on how to traverse Ruby & Rails API docs. Can anyone share the best practice how to read Ruby API docs?

Comment: is there a way to do this without loading the whole file into memory?

Comment: @daveatflow: yes, see my answer below, which reads in the file one line at a time.

Comment: If it's not a csv file, yuo can use something like File.open('file').readlines.each {|line| key,value=line.split(/[$]/); record.create!(key: key, value: value }

Comment: @lokeshjain2008, it refers to the OP's model.

Comment: and for those who get the encoding error, this is how I fixed it.

csv_text = File.read('...').force_encoding("UTF-8")

Comment: `csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :col_sep => ";")` for other separator.

Comment: This method is inefficient! On huge CSV files the ram usage skyrockets. the one below is better.

Comment: @unmircea That is definitely true. Also, you are parsing extremely large files in Ruby?

Comment: @yfeldblum Yes. Trying to import some huge CSVs into Active Record Check out this comparison between all methods. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby

Comment: With many  rows I get: thread failed: inotify event queue has overflowed

Answer (score 227):

Simpler version of yfeldblum's answer, that is simpler and works well also with large files:

```
require 'csv'    

CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
  Moulding.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

No need for `with_indifferent_access` or `symbolize_keys`, and no need to read in the file to a string first.

It doesnt't keep the whole file in memory at once, but reads in line by line and creates a Moulding per line.

Comment: This is better for managing large file sizes right? Does it read in one line at a time?

Comment: @Simon: indeed. It doesnt't keep the whole file in memory at once, but reads in line by line and creates a Moulding per line.

Comment: I have this error, do you know why?: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'siren;nom_ent;adresse;complement_adresse;cp_ville;pays;region;departement;activite;date;nb_salaries;nom;prenom;civilite;adr_mail;libele_acti;categorie;tel' for Transaction

Comment: @AlphaNico Create a question with your problem. That error is unrelated to this, your Model objects seem out of sync.

Comment: In this case, how do you write TestCases for this?

Comment: when I do this, I get Errno:ENOENT - it says no such file or directory but I get the CSV text in the error log, so it reads the file. But it specifically fails in the line CSV.foreach(csv_text, headers: true) do |row| 

this was the code:
require 'csv'    
csv_text = File.read('app/assets/csv/plant_table.csv')
CSV.foreach(csv_text, headers: true) do |row|
  Test.create!(row.to_hash)
end

Answer (score 14):

The `smarter_csv` gem was specifically created for this use-case: to read data from CSV file and quickly create database entries.

```
  require 'smarter_csv'
  options = {}
  SmarterCSV.process('input_file.csv', options) do |chunk|
    chunk.each do |data_hash|
      Moulding.create!( data_hash )
    end
  end
```

You can use the option `chunk_size` to read N csv-rows at a time, and then use Resque in the inner loop to generate jobs which will create the new records, rather than creating them right away - this way you can spread the load of generating entries to multiple workers.

See also: 
     https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Comment: As the CSV class is included, I feel it's better to use it instead of adding or installing an additional gem. Granted, you didn't propose that a new gem be added to the application. It's so easy to add a series of individual gems, each for a specific purpose and before you know it your application has excessive dependencies. (I find myself consciously avoiding the addition of any gems. In my shop we need to justify the addition to our teammates.)

Comment: @Tass it's also pretty easy to add a series of individual methods, each for a specific purpose and before you know it your application has excessive logic that you have to maintain. If a gem works, is well maintained, and uses little resources or can be quarantined to the relevant environments (i.e. Staging for production tasks) it seems to me *always* a better option to use the gem. Ruby and Rails are all about writing less code.

Comment: I have the following error, do you know why? ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'siren;nom_ent;adresse;complement_adresse;cp_ville;pays;region;departement;activite;date;nb_salaries;nom;prenom;civilite;adr_mail;libele_acti;categorie;tel' for Transaction

Comment: I tried this on a rake task, console returns:

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515043/unable-to-run-rake-task-with-smarter-csv?noredirect=1#comment72171357_42515043

Comment: looks like someone already replied - just prefix your CSV file location with `./`

Comment: @Tass chunking the CSV processing, improving the speed and saving memory might be a good justification for adding a new gem ;)

Answer (score 5):

You might try [`Upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert):

```
require 'upsert' # add this to your Gemfile
require 'csv'    

u = Upsert.new Moulding.connection, Moulding.table_name
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
  selector = { name: row['name'] } # this treats "name" as the primary key and prevents the creation of duplicates by name
  setter = row.to_hash
  u.row selector, setter
end
```

If this is what you want, you might also consider getting rid of the auto-increment primary key from the table and setting the primary key to `name`. Alternatively, if there is some combination of attributes that form a primary key, use that as the selector. No index is necessary, it will just make it faster.

Answer (score 4):

This can help. It has code examples too:

http://csv-mapper.rubyforge.org/

Or for a rake task for doing the same:

http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212

Comment: http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212

is broken, please, i opened an issue for doing with rake task here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515043/unable-to-run-rake-task-with-smarter-csv

Answer (score 3):

It is better to wrap the database related process inside a `transaction` block. Code snippet blow is a full process of seeding a set of languages to Language model,

```
require 'csv'

namespace :lan do
  desc 'Seed initial languages data with language & code'
  task init_data: :environment do
    puts '>>> Initializing Languages Data Table'
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      csv_path = File.expand_path('languages.csv', File.dirname(__FILE__))
      csv_str = File.read(csv_path)
      csv = CSV.new(csv_str).to_a
      csv.each do |lan_set|
        lan_code = lan_set[0]
        lan_str = lan_set[1]
        Language.create!(language: lan_str, code: lan_code)
        print '.'
      end
    end
    puts ''
    puts '>>> Languages Database Table Initialization Completed'
  end
end
```

Snippet below is a partial of `languages.csv` file,

```
aa,Afar
ab,Abkhazian
af,Afrikaans
ak,Akan
am,Amharic
ar,Arabic
as,Assamese
ay,Aymara
az,Azerbaijani
ba,Bashkir
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to  include it in a rake task. Create import.rake file inside /lib/tasks/ and put this code to that file.

```
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :csv_model_import, [:filename, :model] => [:environment] do |task,args|
  lines = File.new(args[:filename], "r:ISO-8859-1").readlines
  header = lines.shift.strip
  keys = header.split(',')
  lines.each do |line|
    values = line.strip.split(',')
    attributes = Hash[keys.zip values]
    Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(attributes)
  end
end
```

After that run this command in your  terminal `rake csv_model_import[file.csv,Name_of_the_Model]`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old question but it still in first 10 links in google.

It is not very efficient to save rows one-by-one because it cause database call in the loop and you better avoid that, especially when you need to insert huge portions of data.

It's better (and significantly faster) to use batch insert.

```
INSERT INTO `mouldings` (suppliers_code, name, cost)
VALUES
    ('s1', 'supplier1', 1.111), 
    ('s2', 'supplier2', '2.222')
```

You can build such a query manually and than do `Model.connection.execute(RAW SQL STRING)` (not recomended)
or use gem `activerecord-import` (it was first released on 11 Aug 2010) in this case just put data in array `rows` and call `Model.import rows`

[refer to gem docs for details](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem:
https://rubygems.org/gems/active_record_importer

```
class Moulding < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_importable
end
```

Then you may now use:

```
Moulding.import!(file: File.open(PATH_TO_FILE))
```

Just be sure to that your headers match the column names of your table

Answer (score 0):

The following module can be extended on any model and it will import the data according to the column headers defined in the CSV.

**Note:**

- This is a great internal tool, for customer use I would recommend adding safeguards and sanitization
- The column names in the CSV must be exactly like the DB schema or it won't work
- It can be further improved by using the table name to get the headers vs defining them in the file

Create a file named `"csv_importer.rb"` in your `models/concerns` folder

```
module CsvImporter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  
  require 'csv'
  
  def convert_csv_to_book_attributes(csv_path)
    csv_rows = CSV.open(csv_path).each.to_a.compact
    columns = csv_rows[0].map(&:strip).map(&:to_sym)
    csv_rows.shift
    
    return columns, csv_rows
  end
  
  def import_by_csv(csv_path)
    columns, attributes_array = convert_csv_to_book_attributes(csv_path)
    
    message = ""
    begin
      self.import columns, attributes_array, validate: false
      message = "Import Successful."
    rescue => e
      message = e.message
    end
    
    return message
  end
end
```

Add `extend CsvImporter` to whichever model you would like to extend this functionality to.

In your controller you can have an action like the following to utilize this functionality:

```
def import_file
   model_name = params[:table_name].singularize.camelize.constantize
   csv = params[:file].path
   @message = model_name.import_by_csv(csv)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use CSV::Table and use `String.encode(universal_newline: true)`. It converting CRLF and CR to LF

Comment: What is your proposed solution?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to Use SmartCSV

```
all_data = SmarterCSV.process(
             params[:file].tempfile, 
             { 
               :col_sep => "\t", 
               :row_sep => "\n" 
             }
           )
```

This represents tab delimited data in each row `"\t"` with rows separated by new lines `"\n"`