# Save .csv file to database not recognizing to_hash method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-2

As per this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file), the following method:

```
require "csv"

def import_vault_data(filename)    
    fn = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{filename}"
    CSV.foreach(fn, :headers => true) do |row|
        House.create!(row.to_hash)    
    end
end
```

is producing this error:

```
undefined method `to_hash' for #<Array:0x104cc07b8>
```

Any clue as to what is missing?

I am using rails 2.3.9

Comment: to_hash is not working on rails 2.3.9 it working on rails > 3

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? I'd guess it is 1.8.

Comment: Good to know. Is there an equivalent method or means to accomplish the same thing for rails 2.3.9?

Comment: see this for ruby 1.8.7 - http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for ruby 1.8.7

```
House.create!(row.hash)
```

Comment: This solved the hash error. Brilliant! It effectively created a a new 'House' record, but all fields were null. I have made sure that fields in the csv are the same name and in the same order as the 'houses' database table. I'm guessing there's some other requirement I'm missing. Moreover, it only created 1 record with null fields. There are 50 records in the csv.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on 'row'. Based on the cell values being returned, it appears as though it doesn't know that the first row are header names. Do I need to specify a certain field delimiter when generating the csv? Or perhaps tell the hash command to use first row as headers? If so how would I do this. I'm guessing out loud.

Comment: I tried this:  csv = CSV.parse(fn, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
        row = Hash[row].with_indifferent_access
        House.create!(Hash[row].symbolize_keys)
    end -- 
It produced the correct number of records in the database, but still all database fields are null.

Answer (score 6):

May be a bit late for the answer but you need to:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
```

as you cant call to_hash unless you have headers in the hash

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
House.create!(Hash[row])
```

Comment: I tried this as well. Worked like a charm! Created database records, but all database fields were null.