# How to import CSV files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, fastercsv

I am making an application in which it import a csv file names user.csv.But the problem i am facing is that it gives an error

ArgumentError in CsvimportController#import

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

And the code of the CsvimportController is

```
require 'csv'
class CsvimportController < ApplicationController
def import

results = import('anas.csv') do
read_attributes_from_file
end


end
end
```

And i have also give the specification of csv-mapper and fastercsv in gem file.

Can anyone help me???

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: please change the action name and try because import is the function of csv lib so you need to give different name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Import Data from a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Railscast 396](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) on how to import data from CSV and Excel files.

The [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) project aims to provide a better dealing with CSV files so it would worth to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use the Gem `smarter_csv`.

All you need to do is this:

```
 require 'smarter_csv'

 def import(filename)
   results = SmarterCSV.process( filename, options_hash )
 end
```

and you need to specify the options in the `options_hash` according to the [documentation of `smarter_csv`](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

There are tons of useful options, including manipulation of the headers, custom-headers, ignoring columns, and type-conversion of values.

If your CSV file is large, you can also chunk the incoming data for parallel processing.