# float reading, lose all the decimal digits. RoR 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, floating-point

I want to read a float from a csv file:
my float is: 0,1660, now I just get the first digit: 0

Here you can see how I am reading it, the float character is in the fourth position of the array row:

```
CSV.foreach(path, {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|

            r = Route.new
            ......
            ....
            r.rate = row [3]
```

How can I get the whole number? What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write like that "0.1660" not "0,1660". Ruby is not working with decimal number via comma.

```
[1] pry(main)> 0.111
=> 0.111
[2] pry(main)> 0,111
SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting $end
0,111
```

Comment: but the problem is that the file I get is already written like this: 0,1660

Comment: If you say that the problem is not about comma, problem should be your reading tech. You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4410880/665123

Comment: You can convert the file text on the fly using `row[3].sub(',','.')`

Comment: mm.. problem should be about reading the file, because I just wrote row[3].sub(',','.') and I get this error: undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass