# Rails CSV Import - Uninitialised constant Object::Points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV file into an existing table in my SQLite3 database on a rails project.

I have tried the correct answer on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file) but I get the error:

```
uninitialised constant Object::Points
```

Here is my data.csv file which is in my main directory:

```
Item,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007
AA2,43,34,23,52,24
TT2,48,39,29,23,29
```

Here is my model file which is saved in app\models\points.rb:

```
class Points < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Item, :2003, :2004, :2005, :2006, :2007
end
```

Here is my migration file which is saved in db\migrate\20130709123346_create_points.rb:

```
class CreatePoints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :points do |t|
      t.varchar(255) :Item
      t.integer :"2003"
      t.integer :"2004"
      t.integer :"2005"
      t.integer :"2006"
      t.integer :"2007"  

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Below is what I have tried based on the correct solution linked above:

1. Created new file called import.rake and saved it in lib\tasks\import.rake:

   ```
   require 'csv'    

   csv_text = File.read('data.csv')
   csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
   csv.each do |row|
     Points.create!(row.to_hash)
   end
   ```
2. Then I ran `bundle exec rake import.rake` in the command line.

After running this I get the error:

```
uninitialised constant Object::Points
```

I must be missing something which causes this error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the content of your `import.rake` as an actual task. Also, as your code stands, rake knows nothing about your Rails environment, which is why it can't find `Points`. For example

```
require 'csv'

namespace :import do
  task :points => :environment do
    csv_text = File.read('data.csv')
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      Points.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Then from the command line

```
bundle exec rake import:points
```

The `=> :environment` dependency on the task is what kicks off the Rails environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I run the task it now returns the error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`. I removed the first `end` in the task but then it then returns a slightly different error: `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`.

Comment: @LogiKal as it stands that's outside the scope of this question. There is no block closure issue in the code I've provided above. I unfortunately can't fix syntax errors for code I can't see.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I could find the code which is causing the problem?

Comment: The console will tell you the exact line the error is occurring. That should give you a good idea. Beyond that though, you're better off creating a new question with the related code, as I simply would be guessing otherwise.