# Update table of running results in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a CSV file with finishing places in a marathon that looks like this:

```
name,place
Sarah,1
Kane,5
John,7
```

and so on...

I currently have a rails app that can take the above information in a CSV format and display it as a table.

What I'm trying to do is set the app up so that it displays a table with the runners names as rows and then the five most recent places they came in a run i.e. I would import a new CSV file after each marathon and the table would add the place data in a new column (too a maximum of five) rather than overwrite the previous race results which my app currently does.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't it be useful to adding the columns marathon-`location` and the `date`, with these extra columns you can easily add data at the end of the table and differ it from previous data...

Comment: Thanks for responding @TheChamp but I don't see how that solves the problem. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the import of CSV files, there are already [other great posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file) on stackoverflow.

Your current model is designed to show the 5 most recent places people came in a run.

```
 __________________________________________
| name | place_1 | place_2 | ... | place_5 |
|------|---------|---------|-----|---------|
| John |    1    |    3    | ... |    4    |
| Ann  |    2    |    1    | ... |    2    |
| Tim  |    3    |    2    | ... |    1    |
| Jack |    4    |    5    | ... |    5    |
| Joy  |    5    |    4    | ... |    3    |
 ------------------------------------------
```

The problem with this schema is that when you decide to enter data about a sixth race, you will have to delete data from a previous race or you will have to add a new column, both being a pain.

My suggestion to you is that you change your schema accordingly:

```
 ______________________________________
| name |  place  | location |   date   |
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| John |    1    | New York |11-11-2013|
| Ann  |    2    | New York |11-11-2013|
| Tim  |    3    | New York |11-11-2013|
| Jack |    4    | New York |11-11-2013|
| Joy  |    5    | New York |11-11-2013|
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| John |    3    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
| Ann  |    1    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
| Tim  |    2    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
| Jack |    5    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
| Joy  |    4    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| John |    4    | London   |01-02-2014|
| Ann  |    2    | London   |01-02-2014|
| Tim  |    1    | London   |01-02-2014|
| Jack |    5    | London   |01-02-2014|
| Joy  |    3    | London   |01-02-2014|
 --------------------------------------
```

With this structure you can easily differ the different races either by `location` or their `date`. You won't have to delete data as you can just add new data to the end of the table... This is also possible with CSV.

**Update**

This data can easily be accessed and sorted with some simply queries:

```
# get's all of John's races and orders them by the date descending
Race.where(:name => "John").order("date DESC")

 ______________________________________
| name |  place  | location |   date   |
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| John |    4    | London   |01-02-2014|
| John |    3    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
| John |    1    | New York |11-11-2013|
 --------------------------------------
```

If you only want to get the last 2 results for instance, simply add a `limit`

```
# get the 2 newest races from John
Race.where(:name => "John").order("date DESC").limit(2)

 ______________________________________
| name |  place  | location |   date   |
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| John |    4    | London   |01-02-2014|
| John |    3    | Chigaco  |24-01-2014|
 --------------------------------------
```

I hope this gives you a good idea, if I should clear some more things up, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Oh I see. But wouldn't we just run into the same problem for example if we have more races in Sydney and Barcelona then we have reached the maximum allowed of five past results (given New York, Chicago and London from above). Then another race is run in Paris how will the results from New York disappear to make room for the newer Paris result?

Comment: As I understand it your goal is to get the data from the last 5 races, and that is just a matter of `SQL queries`, for instance, I can get John's last 2 places with `Race.where(:name => "John").order("date DESC").limit(2)`

This can get way more complex, but your desired result will be quit easy to get.