# Importing CSV into Postgresql with duplicate values that are not duplicate rows

Tags: ruby, csv, import, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I am using Rails 4 and postgresql database and I have a question about entering in a CSV dataset into the database.

```
Date    Advertiser Name Impressions Clicks  CPM     CPA     CPC     CTR
10/21/13    Advertiser 1    77         0    4.05    0.00    0.00    0.00
10/21/13    Advertiser 2    10732      23   5.18    0.00    2.42    0.21
10/21/13    Advertiser 3    16941      14   4.64    11.23   5.62    0.08
10/22/13    Advertiser 1    59         0    3.67    0.00    0.00    0.00
10/22/13    Advertiser 2    10130      15   5.24    53.05   3.54    0.15
10/22/13    Advertiser 3    18400      22   4.59    10.55   3.84    0.12
10/23/13    Advertiser 1    77         0    4.06    0.00    0.00    0.00
10/23/13    Advertiser 2    9520      22    5.58    26.58   2.42    0.23
```

Using the data above I need to create a show page for each Advertiser.

Ultimately I need to have a list of Advertiser's that I can click on any one of them and go to their show page and display the informations relevant to each advertiser (impressions, clicks, cpm, etc)

Where I am confused is how to import the CSV data when there are rows with duplicate Advertiser's, but the other columns contain relevant and non duplicate information. How can I set up my database tables so that I will not have duplicate Advertiser's and still import and then display the correct information?

Comment: if there is a duplicate advisor, which row do you want to show? The most recent? or?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the data needs to be displayed as a graph. All of the data related to an advertisor needs to be displayed over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating two different models I just created 1 advertiser model and inputted the complete dataset into that model.

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import advertisers from csv file"
task :import => [:environment] do
  CSV.foreach('db/MediaMathPerformanceReport.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    Advertiser.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

After the data was imported by the above rake task, I simply set up the show route as follows:

```
def show
  @advertiser = Advertiser.where(advertiser_name: advertiser_name)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create two models: Advertiser and Site.  (or maybe date).

Advertiser "has many" Sites, and Site "has one" advertiser.  This association will allow you to import your data correctly.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: So after I create these two models of Advertiser and Date, how would I import the data? would it all just be within one import rake task or would it have to be separate? Do I just do the import in one task shown [here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file)

Comment: I would probably create an import rake.  You will need to loop through each line.  I usually like to make find_or_create(id) methods.  So for you this method would return an existing Advertiser, or a new one with that id.  Then insert a Site and set the advertiser.  I couldn't find a better video, but here is many-to-many (which is not what you have) http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: You can use the link you gave as a starting place