# What is the best way to import multiple .csv files into different entities to a sqlite database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, csv

I have multiple .csv files which I need to import to a sqlite database using active record as an ORM, but I need each of these .csv imported in a different table, while most of them have the same structure.

What is the best way to do this, and is there any efficient way to automate this process in Rails?

I would appreciate you opinions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: Graeme, thx for the suggestion, I saw that answer, but my question is a bit different, because I have multiple CSV files which I need to load into the same database, and not only one CSV file. Any idea for that?