# Ruby/Rails, Parsing CSV with line break between quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Is there any way to tell the CSV object that a line break between quotes is not a row delimiter?

My CSV file is:

```
"a","b","c"
1,"some
text with line break",21
2,"blah",4
```

My code is:

```
CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true) do |row|
  puts row
end
```

I want it to return only two rows, but it returns three.

Comment: If line break is not the row delimiter, then what is?

Comment: Line break is row delimiter but when new line occurres between quotes eg. "asd \n asdf" it shouldn't be treated as two rows.

Comment: it returns exact three rows - and it is the way it should work. but could return four if your comment wasn't true. in other way all of your rows would suggested as one row... isn't it?

Comment: you can pre-process each text parts inside quotes with regexp and delete any internal "\n"

Comment: Excluding header it returns three rows: [["1","some"],["text with line break", "21"],["2","blah","3"]]. I want it to returns two rows: [["1", "some\n text with line break","21"], ["2","blah","4"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're (wrongly) judging the number of rows by the number of printed lines. It returns **two**. Go figure:

```
[4] pry(main)> CSV.foreach('example.csv', headers: true).to_a
=> [
 #<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"some\ntext with line break" "c":"21">,
 #<CSV::Row "a":"2" "b":"blah" "c":"4">
]
```

Your code outputs three lines because you're printing the rows out and line break is printed as-is. That makes it look as if one row became two. **Thinking the same way**, I'd say that *your source CSV contains 4 (four!) rows*. And that isn't really true.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can set your header into true then to show your data `row.to_hash`. Example:

```
CSV.foreach("/home/akbar/text.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  puts row.to_hash
end
```

The result is:

```
1.9.3p194 :034 > CSV.foreach("/home/akbar/text.csv", headers: true) do |x|
1.9.3p194 :035 >     puts x.to_hash
1.9.3p194 :036?>   end
{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"some\ntext with line break", "c"=>"21"}
{"a"=>"2", "b"=>"blah", "c"=>"4"}
```

For more information  see "[ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file)".

Comment: You need to provide backing proof that this will solve the question the OP is asking. Instead of throwing a piece of code, explain why it's the right answer.

Comment: @theTinMan, thanks for your suggestion. I have to do more clearly to answer.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. While we can answer with code only, that's discouraged. Code with no explanation solves the initial question but does not teach so that the situation can be avoided in the future. It's akin to giving the user a fish versus teaching them how to fish. Also, it isn't necessary to add "update" or "updated" when making a change. We can see when and what changed by looking at the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

For those who getting trouble when trying to read a CSV file that contains a line break in any row, just read it with `row_sep: '\r\n'`

```
data = CSV.read('your_file.csv', row_sep: "\r\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It exactly fixes my issue. In my csv file, header, or field value could contain line break like `"abc\ndef "`, but all line break for each row is "\r\n". `row_sep: "\r\n"` solves the issue perfectly