# Rails - Can't import data from CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

I am trying to import data from a CSV file, I don't want to save the file. I have found a similar question here: [Ruby on Rails - Import Data from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file)

However, when I try and use this solution I get an error.

My Form is as follows:

```
Import a CSV file
<%= file_field_tag :file %>

<div class="actions form-group" id="button_text">
<p>
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary button-submit") do %>
Submit
<% end %>
```

On the new page the submission of this form calls the create action, the create action then calls the line:

```
Product.import(params[:file])
```

I have the following import method in my model:

```
def self.import(myfile)
    require 'csv'    

    csv_text = File.read(myfile)
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|

    end
end
```

where 'myfile' is params[:file].

I am aware I am not doing anything with the data yet. I am getting an error with line `csv_text = File.read(myfile)` which is: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - X.csv

When looking for a solution I have seen .path is used. If i change this line to `csv_text = File.read(myfile.path)` I get the error: undefined method `path' for "X.csv":String

Can anybody help? I feel like I must be very close to a solution but I just keep going round and round between these two errors. Is it possible to get the data from the csv without saving it first?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this way
.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(<object>, url: <path>, method: :post, remote: :true, html: {
  multipart: true, }) do |f| %>
    <input type="file" name="file_batch_upload"  accept=".csv />
<% end %>
```

//Define that function

```
def self.import(file)
    require 'csv'    

    csv_text = File.read(file.tempfile)
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
     //row["name"]
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain this at all? I can't get this to work, .tempfile is undefined for file which is a string

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to remember with file uploads is that the rendered form's encoding MUST be set to `multipart/form-data`. I guess you have that maintained.

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
<% end %>
```

Now in controller you will have access to `IO` object via `params`. The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO.

The object will have an `original_filename` attribute containing the name the file had on the user's computer and a `content_type` attribute containing the `MIME` type of the uploaded file.

You can either move the temporary file to some dir in your `public` directory or simple use and throw away.

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:file]

  # Moving the file to some safe place; as tmp files will be flushed timely
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

---

for you, you can leverage the `tempfile` attribute in the `IO` object. The actual file is accessible via the `tempfile` accessor, though some of its interface is available directly for convenience.

So, this should work

```
...
csv_text = File.read(file.tempfile)
...
```

## Update

```
> uploaded_io = params[:file]
=> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f4154fe9a38
 @content_type="application/pdf",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"3423loadshedding.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n",
 @original_filename="3423loadshedding.pdf",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20160421-14883-1lv0qtq.pdf>>

[2] pry(#<PostsController>)> uploaded_io.tempfile
=> #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20160421-14883-1lv0qtq.pdf>

> uploaded_io.tempfile.class
=> Tempfile
```

For Error

```
ProductsController#upload No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /<path to my app>/public/uploads/X.csv
```

You need to first create the folder `public/uploads`

```
$ mkdir public/uploads
```

Now try; the file should be moved. This is how `Paperclip` and `Carrierwave` manage uploaded files.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question..

I am getting the error : Errno::ENOENT in ProductsController#upload
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /<path to my app>/public/uploads/X.csv

When you say I can move the temporary file to a dir in my public directory did you mean manually? Is there no way to do this in the program?

Comment: I think I may have it with 

uploaded_io = params[:file].tempfile
    csv_text = File.read(uploaded_io)

but need to test properly