# Rails: Importing from CSV to ActiveRecord gives "NoMethodError: undefined method" for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I am new to Rails, and am doing a simple db import but cannot resolve an error.

I have data like so in a CSV:

```
"Symbol","Name","LastSale","MarketCap","IPOyear","Sector","industry","Summary Quote",
"DDD","3D Systems Corporation","12.95","$1.45B","n/a","Technology","Computer Software: Prepackaged Software","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ddd",
```

I create a model for the entries with the following command:

```
bin/rails generate model Companies Symbol:string Name:string LastSale:string MarketCap:string IPOyear:string Sector:string Industry:string SummaryQuote:string
```

...I run db:migrate, and then try to import the data to the model with this rake task:

```
  task :populate => :environment do
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file
    CSV.foreach("companylist.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
      Company.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
```

This results in an error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'industry' for Company.
```

However, the "Company" model was created with an Industry atrribute--I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: is it because you used uppercase letters for the column names, i.e. `Industry`, not `industry`?

Comment: Ruby is case-sensitive. I'm not sure whether CSV's `row.to_hash` does the downcasing of the column names but it seems it does. When the hash reaches your model it tries to assign to the `industry` attribute which is not there. There is the `Industry` one but it doesn't match.

Comment: Changing the column names to match the attributes exactly resolves that issue, but creates a new error, `"ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute ' ' for Company."`

Comment: Remove ending commas from each line of your CSV.

Comment: Is there a dangling column without a header in your CSV? Check out the output of the `row.to_hash` before creating the model and make sure the structure is as you expect.

Comment: @mudasobwa Won't `row.reject { |e| e.strip.empty? }` lead to structure corruption in case a middle column has no value?

Comment: @NicNilov Oh, indeed, thanks, my bad. I updated a comment, it anyway won’t fix anything since the problem is _with header_.

Comment: @NicNilov @mudasobwa I inserted `row.delete(nil)` before  `Company.create!(row.to_hash) `, which seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the table field name, I think the Field name in table is 'Industry' instead of industry.
Best