# RoR - import csv to MySQL DB with smarterCSV gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, activerecord, smartercsv

I'm trying to upload a csv file with a lot of posible clients (15000) on a MySQL table. I want to keep on a table for later retrieve info, complete forms and make users.

Now i'm on the beginning, trying to import the csv to the MySQL.

I read some solutions that takes **smarterCSV gem**, so i must do a migration with the db structure and then execute the rake task or not needed to execute the migration for this?

The kind of code i want to use for import the csv is something like i read on before posts like [Ruby on Rails - Import Data from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410794/ruby-on-rails-import-data-from-a-csv-file)

```
require 'smarter_csv'
  options = {}
  SmarterCSV.process('input_file.csv', options) do |chunk|
    chunk.each do |data_hash|
      Moulding.create!( data_hash )
    end
  end
```

Comment: JFYI, if you're concerned about speed, mysql can import csv natively. It'll be super-duper fast. Obviously, db structure must exist prior to import.

Comment: but if you need to repeat it on a deploy? when you are updating the code?

Comment: You need to reseed database when you update code? How so?

Comment: i'm making this on development, but when we have all done, we must need to upload the code to github repository and run the deploy with capistrano. I want to do this on an authomatic/good way.

Comment: yes, i need to reseed the database when we update production, create the table and info inside when update the code on production.

Answer (score 1):

You may use my importer gem. It also uses SmarterCSV.

https://github.com/michaelnera/active_record_importer