# Trigger events on multiple records in state_machine gem

Tags: state-machine

I am using state_machine for the transition of states in one of my models. The transition is successfully happening on single records. But what to do if I have to trigger an event on multiple records. I can do transition in multiple records with

```
     @records.each &:event
```

But this method executes query as many number of times as there are `@records`. How can I trigger the event to do the state transition with just one query. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails (4), this can be accomplished using [`B#transaction`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) (or `B#save`) as discussed in [SO: save an active records array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292815/save-an-active-records-array).

I benchmarked running a simple state_machine event on 200 records and the results are noted below.

Instead of:

```
@records.each &:event
# Completed 302 Found in 1700ms (ActiveRecord: 778.6ms)
```

do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @records.each &:event
end
# Completed 302 Found in 977ms (ActiveRecord: 73.4ms)
```

As noted in the aforelinked SO answer, this will wrap those transactions as one atomic action.

**Note**: There are likely error-handling edge-cases that this doesn't address.